# Meteor Mongo db doesn't find all items in collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have simple chat application. When I want to get all data from:

```
Conversations.find().count()
```

collection I get only 2 records, but if I put same code in console I get 3 records. Im using Meteor 1.6.1.1 and mongo 1.4.7 and

```
meteor update --all-packages
```

My json in mongoDB looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "cd2vBQmFCLPGiCoHw", "users" : "GAJqvsBr4xH79rRbY,v9CRhv2qJrKxDMAmZ" }
```

Comment: Do you run `Conversations.find().count()` on the server or on the client?

Comment: `Conversations.find().count()` on cilent side and on server i use `db.Conversations.find().count()` on console.

Comment: In mongodb server, what does it return? db.<yourCollection>.count()

Comment: So please add your publication. It seems, that your client does not receive all documents. The only "truth" about your collection is on the server - on the client you see only those documents you subscribed to.

Comment: when i put in cilent side `Conversations.find().fetch()` i get 

`0:{_id: "cd2vBQmFCLPGiCoHw", users: "GAJqvsBr4xH79rRbY,v9CRhv2qJrKxDMAmZ"}
1:{_id: "PtubTmG5xZ7QJDEta", users: "GAJqvsBr4xH79rRbY,fF2oxKnnBAhQok4w8"}` and if i put the same code i console i get `{ "_id" : "cd2vBQmFCLPGiCoHw", "users" : "GAJqvsBr4xH79rRbY,v9CRhv2qJrKxDMAmZ" }
{ "_id" : "PtubTmG5xZ7QJDEta", "users" : "GAJqvsBr4xH79rRbY,fF2oxKnnBAhQok4w8" }
{ "_id" : "TysTEuMnwcNiYjkGD", "users" : "v9CRhv2qJrKxDMAmZ,fF2oxKnnBAhQok4w8" }` One give me 3 records and another 2